# Which versions of Windows have NFS clients?

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing, nfs

Which versions of Windows currently support mounting of Network File System (NFS) shares without the installation of 3rd party software?

I know that Windows 10 Enterprise editions have always had an NFS client and recently Microsoft has extended this to Windows 10 Pro, but I can't find much information about Windows 10 Home or previous versions of Windows.

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: Windows 8 is a No (Enterprise only), Can be enabled in W7 Ulitmate....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769923/services-for-nfs-availability-in-windows-8-editions

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft article
[Services for NFS availability in Windows 8 editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769923/services-for-nfs-availability-in-windows-8-editions),
an NFS client is available on:

- Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate editions
- Windows 8 Enterprise edition
- Windows 10 Pro edition and higher
  (not in the above article, but you already found that info).